# Stacked column chart in Google Sheets taking data from multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a bunch of book club "star" votes in a table, broken into columns by participant. Some cells are blank where a participant didn't assign a rating.

```
          A  B  C
Title 1   3  4  2
Title 2   5  5  4
Title 3   2     2
Title 4   1  4  3
```

I want a stacked column chart (histogram?) with 5 bars, one for each possible star rating subdivided by the person making the rating. So for the above, it would look something like:

```
   C     C
   C  C  B  B
A  A  A  B  A
-------------
1  2  3  4  5
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this with Google Sheets. Both the standard Setup and "switch rows/columns" are wrong. I think maybe I need to pre-analyse the data somehow?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(B2:D="",,"♠"&B2:D&"♦"&B1:D1),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I must confess, I'm a bit lost in the formula you're proposing. Can you please give me some idea of what the card suits mean and what the `999^99` is for?

Comment: sure, card symbols mean nothing. its added there so later it could be used in SPLIT as separator. 9^9 also means nothing. it can be any big number you wish for but it always should be higher than total number of rows in your sheet

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to count the quantity of each star type broken down by person, and organize your data like this for the table:

```
Star Amt A  B  C
1 Star   1  0  0
2 Star   1  0  2
3 Star   1  0  1
4 Star   0  2  1
5 Star   1  1  0
```

The numbers in the table represent the number of times the user (column) voted a particular star amount (row).

Maybe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rFXcdzKal0) can help too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not clear how I should dynamically reformat my data to get it into the layout you propose. With 5×N cells filled with COUNT functions? That seems uber hacky. With a pivot table? I didn't have much success figuring that out either.