# How to create a Stacked Versus Bar Chart in Google Sheet that is capable of stacking more than 2 data?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a Versus Chart in google sheet from a data set that looks like this:

```
==============================================
|   Date   |  Curator Rating  |  SME Rating  |
==============================================
| 09/01/23 |         3        |       3      |
==============================================
| 09/01/23 |         2        |       1      |
==============================================
| 09/01/23 |         4        |       5      |
==============================================
| 09/01/23 |         1        |       1      |
==============================================
| 09/01/23 |         4        |       4      |
==============================================
| 09/01/23 |         5        |       4      |
==============================================
```

I want to create a Versus Chart of the Curator and SME rating represented by a Stacked Bar. The X-axis is for the Curator Rating from 1 to 5. The Y-axis is the total count per rating.

Below is a sample chart that I want to achieve( the data is not the same above)
[What I am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh0My.png)

Is it possible? Or what other options can I use to achieve at least a similar representation of the ratings.

Comment: `Below is a sample chart that I want to achieve( the data is not the same above)` Would you please edit the data in your question (or edit your graph) so that the data aligns with the expected outcome.

Comment: Related question: [Stacked column chart in Google Sheets taking data from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562458/1330560)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacked column chart in Google Sheets taking data from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561392/stacked-column-chart-in-google-sheets-taking-data-from-multiple-columns)

Comment: Hello Ted, here is the link of the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j3JNfzXBiWhtqKzMsyDQx4LvKnBrNpltxubFUcTbWos/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in two parts:

1. Format the data for the graph
2. design the graph

This answer implements the method described by @player0 in [Google Sheets : simple query with pivot clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71502476/1330560)

---

**Format the data**

Use this formula in cell:

`=QUERY({C1:E, E1:E},"select Col2,count(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col4", 1)`

In this example,

- Column C is used solely to limit the number of rows (`where Col1 is not null`). Another column could be used for this.
- Column D ("Curator rating") is used for the rows (`group by Col2`)
- Column E is accessible as both Col3 and Col4

  - Col3 is used to count the SME instances (`count(Col3)`)
  - Col4 is used to create a pivot table whether the SME values are in the columns (`pivot Col4`)

---

**RESULTS**

[image: snapshot]

---

There are certain aspects of the graph (such as the tick marks on the vertical axis, Legend title, etc) that the OP should pursue.